# Socket Port Scanner does not find any valid open ports

Tags: python, sockets, port

I'm currently coding a port scanner where you can import a list of ips and the program will check all of them for open ports.

The problem is, that the port scanner finds 5 valid ports on 5 different ips and then only finds invalid open ports. The list im trying are my own servers and all the ports im testing are opened. I can even see them when im using this website for testing: https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

The program is multi-threaded.

I've tried many different things, using `connect_ex()` instead of of `connect()` but nothing worked.

```
def scanner(host):

    global checked
    checked +=1
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(1)
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    try:
        s.connect((host,25))
        s.close()
        write_console("success", "Host: " + host + " offener Port: 25")
        write(host + ":25", output_file)

    except Exception as e:
        write_console("error", "Host: " + host + " Port: 25")

    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((host,587))
        s.close()
        write_console("success", "Host: " + host + " offener Port: 587")
        write(host + ":587", output_file)

    except:
        write_console("error", "Host: " + host + " Port: 587")
```

Comment: *only finds invalid open ports...* What is an *invalid open port*, I don't even know what means? *The program is multi-threaded...* not the code you've show here. You realize you're only testing to see if ports 25 and 587 are open, and no others.

Comment: By invalid ports i mean that the program does not find ports that are open. 25 and 587 are opened but the program is not able to detect those. The script is multi-threaded, yes, but the code i posted is just the function which is getting called by the threads.

Comment: You need to more carefully check *why* the failures are occurring. You catch exceptions, that exception will tell you a great deal. Edit your question and post the complete stacktrace of the exception(s).

Comment: By the way, to print out the exception, add `import traceback` to the imports and add `traceback.print_exc()` to your exception handlers.